# proving that no positive integer can be written in two different ways as the sum of distinct non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

How to prove that no positive integer can be written in two different ways as the sum of distinct non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Have you tried computing the Fibonacci representation of some concrete numbers, like $20, 50, 100$?

Comment: I did, but I'm having trouble with writing the proof.